# Webstorm JS resolve variables/methods in injected packages

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I just started using Webstorm, and would like to enable variable resolving for injected objects.

E.g

if i do this.

```
const path = require('path');
```

and type path.re
the webstorm will offer options like "resolve", "relative" etc

however if i use dependency injection, then it no longer works.

```
//in file 1
doSomething( {path: path} );

//then , in file 2
function doSomething( params ) {
    const {path} = params;
    //i type path.re    and code completion no longer works, and i
    //get unresolved variable warnings if i use anything in path.
}
```

Comment: in file2, how can the IDE know what 'params' type is? Please can you provide the full code snippet? From your description, I don't understand what should be completed

Comment: there is a logical path from const path variable to the object passed into doSomething and from there into local path inside doSomething function.

Code completion even works for some injected properties, but not all.

simply put, the const {path} = params; is the same object as require('path');